# Vars $_GET not work with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file with follow content:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^produto/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /teste/testeproduto/produto.php?id=$2&nome=$1 [NC]
```

And in my php file I'm using it:

```
   print_r($_GET);
```

But it's not working (get $_GET vars).
What I do?

Comment: What URL are you expecting to find something with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [QSA,NC] instead of [NC] at the end of your RewriteRule, to add the Query String (the part after the question mark) to the redirected URL.

From Apache 2.2 documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa):

When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

Comment: The url that i'm passed is : http://192.168.1.108/teste/testeproduto/produto/camiseta-azul-bege/580/

Comment: Thats the incoming URL from the visitor? Do you have a Rewrite Base, or is the .htaccess file not in the root folder? (See my comment below about the missing leading slash)

Comment: I try put [QSA,NC] in end of line but not work. I'm testing in two different servers and first server $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] isn't present

Comment: this .htacces is /var/www/teste/testeproduto/.htaccess

Comment: Then your best bet is to add a nice "phpinfo();" at the beginning of produto.php, so you can see what you receive. FYI, it works on my box (apache 2.2 on Debian squeeze), using http://localhost/teste/testeproduto/produto/camiseta-azul-bege/580 and print_r($_GET) gives me Array ( [id] => 580 [nome] => camiseta-azul-bege ) )

Comment: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING  no value
REQUEST_URI  /teste/testeproduto/produto/camiseta-azul-bege/580/
SCRIPT_NAME  /teste/testeproduto/produto.php
PATH_INFO  /camiseta-azul-bege/580/
PATH_TRANSLATED  /var/www/camiseta-azul-bege/580/

Comment: Could you change your RewriteRule to [NC,R=301] to see the real rewritten URL instead of silently serving it ?

Comment: I realized that the htaccess is not working within the subdirectory. Is taking root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is at least one syntax error in your string. First, I believe you need a leading slash, and second you don't need the trailing question mark unless you are trying to make the trailing slash optional. In combination, these two elements may be affecting the pattern matching.

RewriteRule ^/produto/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/$

Assumes the incoming URL is http://yourdomain.com/produto/blah123/456/

Comment: No, you musn't put the leading slash, or the rewriterule won't match.